# Is it possible to print variables into file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to generate a log with using the default SQL Server log. If I use:

```
SET @IPE = 'bcp SELECT ''Test ''' + @SQLEXE  +  'queryout'  + @Path + '1b_Log_change_log_entry.txt -c '+ @Servername +' '+ @Authentification +''
```

it doens't work, because the result is:

```
Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]  [-l login timeout]
```

**NULL**

Comment: No `@SQLEXE`, no `@Path`, no `@Servername`, no `@Authentification`, we can't help you on this. Obviously though, `bcp` is not being used correctly. Whatever is coming up after `{query}`, it's not one of the three `'in', 'out' or 'format'`. Try printing `@IPE` and examining its correctness.

Comment: Might not be the only issue, but you have no spaces before or after the `queryout` keyword in the `@IPE` string you're building, so I expect that's likely to cause an issue regardless (unless `@SQLEXE` ends with a space and `@Path` begins with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using the bcp utility and the argument -o